# Where is the CMake install option in Android Studio 3.2.1?

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, android-studio-3.2

I am trying to install NDK in Android Studio 3.2.1 and I am following the procedure described [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides)

It says I need to select LLDB, Cmake and NDK form the list in the SDK Manager,but I can only see LLDB and NDK in my computer, and CMake is absent

What do I need to do to install CMake and start coding using C? Or is installing just LLDB and NDK enough?

Comment: probably this will help https://github.com/russell-shizhen/JniExample

Comment: @shizen it's a good blog but doesn't show how to get Cmake

Comment: It should by default appear in your SDK Manager dialog as said in your inlined link. wasn't it there?

Comment: @shizhen no it's not there, only NDK and LLDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs on developer.android site:

> Android Studio supports CMake, which is good for cross-platform projects, and ndk-build, which can be faster than CMake but only supports Android. Using both CMake and ndk-build in the same module is not currently supported.

You can only use one of the Cmake or NDK(as you see NDk is better but only developed for Android).

[here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code) is link of documentation for more info.

If you still have problem with installing cmake by sdk manager, make sure you are using 64 bit version of android studio.

for more information about how you can install Cmake or NDK you can see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43653522/7135845)

Comment: Then how do I get Cmake?

Comment: When making a new project after installing installing NDK and LLDB, it gives the error "Failed to find CMake.
Install CMake and sync project"

Comment: @user13267 Check if you are using 64 bit version of Android Studio. In Android Studio 32 bit, cmake will not appear in sdk manager!

Comment: looks like the NDK installation happened properly at least. Is there any way to instruct android studio to use ndk-build instead of cmake for compiling C code?

Comment: @user13267 see this answer (part NDK) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43653522/7135845

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link

Comment: @user13267 you're welcome. if my answer or this link help you to find a solution, you can accept it and upvote it to help other people in the future that have the same problem.

Comment: Please add the link to your answer and I will accept it

Comment: @user13267 I add the link to my answer.